# Отложенный постинг

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите как создается отложенный постинг на примере того же сайта Вконтакте. Cron программно задать нельзя, цикл не вариант, если сделать циклом и к примеру 80 человек выбрали одно и тоже время то интервал собьется пока дойдет до 80 пользователя. Задача сделать на сайте следующее. Пользователь выбирает дату и(или) время, например каждые 5 минут, выбирает свое сообщество. И по истечении времени ему в сообщество должен публиковаться пост.

Comment: что если просто показывать посты время публикации которых >= now() ORDER by datetime_public DESC ?

Comment: @Alex речь не про показ на сайте, а про публикацию контента в сторонние источники, видимо куда то в ВК

Comment: в чем проблема к кроном? ее лучше решите, а не костыли придуывайте

Comment: Ну и как программно через php мне создавать на хостинге cron задачи для каждого пользователя сайта?

Comment: Легко, создаете задачу общую для всех пользователей, в ней смотрите если пришло время постить запись - вы это делаете от имени пользователя и всё

Comment: Ну тогда получается если у меня на одно и тоже время 60 пользователей, это как минимум 60 запросов если делать только 1 запрос к api. Пусть 1 запрос = 1 секунде, получается что 60-й пользователь на 60 сек будет отставать?

Comment: Не очень понятно, публикация "у себя" или в тот же ВК. Но крон не нужен во всех случаях. У ВК в API есть параметр publish_date, раньше которого отправленное сообщение показано не будет, а "у себя" можно сделать такой же.

Comment: publish_date не подходит для моих целей. Меня вообще интересует как сделать задачу в которой может быть от 1 до 5 запросов к api и может быть огромное кол-во пользователей на одно и тоже время.

Answer (score 1):

**Предупреждение - костыль адского уровня!**

Если правильно понял вопрос, требуется одновременно, без особых задержек, постить много постов через API (по сути делать запросы). Видится мне один очень косой, костыльный и не идеальный, но все же выход. Создать каких 100 cron-задач, запускающих один и тот же скрипт, а скрипт в свою очередь делает следующее:

- Запрашивает 1 пост, из таблицы отложенных постов
- Смотрит, не захватил ли этот пост другой экземпляр скрипта (создать какой-нибудь флаг в таблице, либо держать информацию о таких флагах для каждого поста в общем кеше, например при помощи memcached или redis)
- Если пост не захвачен - пометить его как "захваченный" и начать постить его
- Пометить как "выполнено", чтобы пост снова не попался скрипту.

По идее должно получится что-то вроде параллельного выполнения. Таким образом можно будет без особых задержек постить около 100 постов. Если выше - конечно возникнет задержка (которая будет равна интервалу работы крона). но это все только в теории. Сам никогда подобного не делал, и не знаю каким будет поведение такого костыля.

Answer (score 0):

Решается с помощью очередей.

Есть табличка в базе, в которую пишем информацию о будущих постах. Скрипт по крону забирает некоторое количество записей, постит их и помечает в табличке как выполненные.

Answer (score 0):

Можно отправлять запросы к api одновременно с помощью Multi Curl

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]